# can anyone help? I want to convert this for loop to the recursive version

Tags: python, recursion

```
G = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]


def IsDominate(A, S, v):
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        vert = S[i]
        if (A[vert][v] == 1):
            return True
    return False

print(IsDominate(G, [0, 3, 2], 1))
```

Basically the function takes as input the adjacency matrix A of a graph G, a subset S of its vertices and a vertex v. The function returns true if S dominates v and false otherwise.

Here is my wron code using recursion:

```
def ISDominate(A, S, v, i):
    if i == 0:
        return A[0]
    vert = S[i]
    if (A[vert][v] == 1):
        return True
    return IsDominate(A,S, v, i-1)

print(ISDominate(G, [0, 2, 3], 1, len(G)-1))
```

Comment: did you look at numpy ? or do you really want to make it your self ?

Comment: @user3732793 No, I didnt look at Numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code throws an IndexError when given this adjacency graph:

```
G = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

This is because length of S is smaller than length of G. When it can't return True, it eventually reaches out of index.

To turn your code recursive you can do this:

```
G = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

def IsDominate(A, S, v):
    if A[S[0]][v] == 1:
            return True
    return IsDominate(A,S[1:],v) if S[1:] else False

print(IsDominate(G, [0, 3, 2], 1))
```

Basically check the first entry and call the function recursively without the first entry of S. I do not recommend using recursion here, it does not add efficiency or readability in my opinion.